# how to update google chart dashboard dynamically when selecting an individual response from a google form response sheet e

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-forms

I have a google form response sheet and I have created a separate tab for doing analysis on an individual response. Basically filling out a table which is then used to generate graphs and charts. Each time I need to do analysis on a single response, I have to change the formula to look at the specific response and then drag the formula down to update the whole table and which then creates a column chart in a separate sheet.

My question is- Is there any way I can simply select the response (like a button in the google chart dashboard sheet) which then looks at the response in the response sheet and updates the table in the separate sheet to give the graph accordingly?

I have not used any app script so far in my sheet for the dashboard? It is just a simple data validation method looking at the values from other sheet and gives the graph. Not sure if app script is the solution or any other solutions to work around this.

Help!!

Table to fill from google form:

[image: Image - table to fill from google form]

Google Chart Dashboard:

[image: Image- Google Chart Dashboard*]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query or "if" formulas to do what you are describing. Your query or if statement should point to a cell(s) which is have drop-down data validation lists, which when changed then alter your table, which in turn changes the graphs.

Example 1:

```
=query(Sheet!A:C,"SELECT A WHERE B ='"&D1&"'",0)
```

This query looks at the cell D1 and altered depending on its contents.

Example 2:

```
=if(D1="SOMETHING","DOSOMETHING","ORDOSOMETHINGELSE)
```

In this statement again D1 could be a cell that contains a drop-down list of variable data validation items.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have used `=vlookup(HLOOKUP(indirect("Questions!"&N4),ArrayFormula('Form Responses 2'!$1:$3),3,0),Crietria!$B:$C,2,0)`     as my sheet takes looks at the responses and matches a certain criteria and returns a number based on it. how can I use query function instead of arrayformula so it does the same without me having to change the formula for each response in the array formula`=vlookup(HLOOKUP(indirect("Questions!"&P4),query('Form Responses 2'!$A:$AX,select A WHERE B=?? ),3,0),Crietria!$B:$C,2,0`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I made an example, [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bm6c9g8Fdmb9zL7e-ciMSsttnYtFEfeoZmJ7pjvfZZY/edit#gid=0)